# how can I make a DSN in linux

Tags: linux, odbc

In windows computer I create a DSN for connecting a PI (from OISoft ) database and pull data in excel and others.
Now how can I make a DSN in linux or can use the DSN already created in that windows PC.

Comment: When you use an acronym it's good practice to expand.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSN

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refer to your ODBC library vendor's documentation and/or your ODBC driver vendor's documentation for details.

How these things are handled is very much dependent on how the library does it. You might stick a file somewhere or something.

Answer (score 0):

Linux driver managers (unixODBC and iODBC are the free ones) both use the same configuration files: odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini (or .odbc.ini and .odbcinst.ini in your home directory)

odbc.ini is used to list DSNs:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
MyDSN=MyDriver

[MyDSN]
Driver=MyDriver
Description=This is my DSN and its settings for connecting to MyDriver.
UID=TheUsername
PWD=ThePassword
SOMEOTHERSETTING=etc
```

odbcinst.ini is used to list Drivers:

```
[ODBC Drivers]
MyDriver=Installed

[MyDriver]
Driver=/path/to/driver.so
Description=This is my driver.
```

Both of these are analogous to the entries in the Windows registry at HKLM/Software/ODBC/ODBC.INI and HKLM/Software/ODBC/ODBCINST.INI so you can go and copy the values from there to setup your DSN in linux.

Answer (score -1):

DSNs are a windows-only concept. There's no equivalent on Linux.

Comment: Downvote: This is wrong. DSNs are an ODBC concept and there is at least one ODBC library vendor who supports Linux.

Comment: Maybe, but that's not standard at all. You can't walk up to a Linux box and expect that kind of thing to be present, whereas you CAN walk up to a Windows box and expect DSN support to be present.